# XSLT issue with MSOLEDBSQL provider

Tags: xslt, visual-c++, sql-server-2014, oledb

I am making a dynamic connection with `SqL Server 2014` using `msado15.dll` in `C++` on `Windows Server 2016` and the provider is `MSOLEDBSQL`. The code is breaking at the line where I add `XSL parameter`. I am not getting what is wrong with the statement or with the `XSL file`.

_com_error: *Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal*

```
#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" no_namespace rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
try
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    // Define string variables.
    _bstr_t strCnn("Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;DATABASE=Sample;Data Source=IS-DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");

    _ConnectionPtr mAdoConn;
    _CommandPtr cmd;
    _StreamPtr outStrm;

    const char *xslfile;
    xslfile = "C:\\script\\Test_xsl\\example-html.xsl";

    _variant_t vra(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
    _variant_t vtEmpty(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);


    hr = mAdoConn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed creating record set instancen");
        return 0;
    }


    hr = mAdoConn->Open(strCnn, L"", L"", -1);

    // Set the Command
    hr = cmd.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));

    cmd->ActiveConnection = mAdoConn;
    hr = cmd->put_CommandTimeout(900);

    _bstr_t sqlQuery = "SELECT Id,Title,Artist,Country,Company,Price,Year FROM CDCatalog CD ORDER BY Id FOR XML AUTO";

    hr = cmd->put_CommandText(sqlQuery);

    hr = cmd->Properties->Item[L"XSL"]->put_Value(_variant_t(xslfile));

    // Set-up the output stream
    hr = outStrm.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Stream));

    hr = outStrm->Open(vtEmpty, adModeUnknown, adOpenStreamUnspecified, L"", L"");

    hr = cmd->Properties->Item[L"Output Stream"]->put_Value(_variant_t((IDispatch*)outStrm));

    hr = cmd->Properties->Item[L"Output Encoding"]->put_Value(_variant_t("utf-8")); //ISO-8859-1"));

    hr = cmd->Execute(&vra, &vtEmpty, adExecuteStream);


}
catch (_com_error &ce)
 printf("Error:%s", (char *)ce.Description());

CoUninitialize();
_getch();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What exactly happens when you say " The code is breaking", please provide any exact compiler or run-time error messages you get. As you try to use a particular data base and its API, it might also help to find knowledgeable people if you add a tag for the the database and api you try to use.

Comment: @MartinHonnen updated the error code.
and also this code works when provider is changed to SQLOLEDB but I can't use it as it does not support TLS 1.2